# Basic Authentication redirection after wrong logins

Tags: php, redirect, basic-authentication

How to write php code which count users input in basic auth form and after 3rd time redirect to another page?
So must be algoritm like:

1. If wrong login comes 3times then goto example.com
2. If login correct go to host.com/page1.php
3. If press cancel then echo "`<h1>Authorization Required</h1>`";

   ```
   session_start();

   if(isset($_SESSION['login_attempts'])){ $_SESSION['login_attempts']++; }else{$_SESSION['login_attempts'] = 1;}

   if($_SESSION['login_attempts'] == 3 && $login_failed == true){
       header('Location: http://www.example.com');
       die;
   }

   $_user = 'test1324546';
   $_password = 'test23456';

   if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $_user|| $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $_password ) {    
   header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="hi"');
   header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

   echo "<html><head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head><body>";
   echo "<h1>Authorization Required</h1>";

   exit;
       } else {

       }
   ?>
   ```

Is that correct?

Comment: Another way would be to have a $_POST that you increment everytime auth fails. if (login fail ) { $_POST['loginattemps] = $_POST['loginattemps] +1 }  and if ($_POST['loginattemps] ==3 ) {header}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sessions will be the easiest way but this won't stop bots, as they will clear their session cookie.

Here is some example code.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $_user = 'test1324546';
    $_password = 'test23456';

    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $_user || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $_password ) {

        if(isset($_SESSION['login_attempts'])){ $_SESSION['login_attempts']++; }else{$_SESSION['login_attempts'] = 1;}

        if($_SESSION['login_attempts'] == 3){
            header('Location: http://www.example.com');

            exit;
        } else {
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="hi"');
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

            echo "<html><head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head><body>";
            echo "<h1>Authorization Required</h1>";

            exit;
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: /page1.php');

        exit;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Ok thank you man, it wil be wonderful to see at working example with basic auth. Thanks

Comment: Updated ... I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
header('Location: page1.php'); /* -- Example -- */
```

However, you would need to make sure you have an 'if' statement with 'else' statements that follow if the user didn't login correctly 3 times.

Comment: Could you provide what code you have at the moment so we have something to go by to help you out?